# Show by definition that function $f(x)=x+x^3$ is injective on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let us take $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us assume $x_1\neq x_2$, then:

$$f(x_1)-f(x_2)= x_1+x_1^3-x_2-x_2^3=(x_1-x_2)+(x_1^3-x_2^3)=(x_1-x_2)+(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)=(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+1)$$

I want to show that $f(x_1)-f(x_2)\neq0$, and as $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$ I have two expressions multiplied by each other, so I should justify that both of them are not equal to $0$.

The first expression $(x_1-x_2)$ is different from $0$ by my assumption $x_1\neq x_2$. I do not know what to do with the second one.

I can imagine that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive the whole expression $(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+1)$ is greater than $1$, the same if both arguments are negative, but I do not know what if they have different signs.

Could you please explain me this?

Edit:

Let us use the fact
$(x_1+x_2)^2 \geq 0$, which is equivalent to $x_1x_2 \geq -\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)$, and notice the following:

$$x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+1 \geq x_1^2-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)+x_2^2+1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)+1$$

The last expression is always greater than $1$, so $x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+1>1$, and as a consequence $f(x_1)-f(x_2) \neq 0$.

Comment: Use that $x_1x_2 \geq -\frac{1}{2}x_1^2 - \frac{1}{2}x_2^2$, so that the second expression on the right is always greater than $\frac{1}{2}x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2 + 1 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track!

I would recommend you to notice that:
\begin{align*}
f(x) - f(y) & = x + x^{3} - (y + y^{3})\\\\
& = (x - y) + (x^{3} - y^{3})\\\\
& = (x - y) + (x - y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2})\\\\
& = (x - y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2} + 1)\\\\
& = (x - y)\underbrace{\left[\left(x + \frac{y}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3y^{2}}{4} + 1\right]}_{\geq 1}
\end{align*}

Hence $f(x) - f(y) = 0$ implies that $x - y = 0$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear!

Comment: @gaghan you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I will write $x, y$ instead of $x_1, x_2$ for ease of notation:

Suppose $x^2 + xy + y^2 + 1 = 0$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

By the quadratic formula, we have:

$$x = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{y^2 - 4(y^2 + 1)}}{2} = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{-3y^2 - 4}}{2}$$

Since $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $-3y^2 - 4 < 0$; so, its square root is not a real number. Therefore, there are no real numbers $x, y$ that satisfy the given equation.

---

**Note:** If not appealing to an earlier definition, you could take the derivative and find that it is $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 1 > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$; therefore, this is a strictly increasing polynomial, whence it is injective $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure how you get the expression for $x$.

Comment: @gaghan This is the quadratic formula for equations of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. In this case, we have: $a = 1$, $b = y$, and $c = y^2 + 1$.

Comment: I get it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^3$ are strictly increasing so is their sum $f(x)=x+x^3.$ Therefore it is injective. That's not a direct proof, but the shortest one, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach of showing that $f(x)= x + x^3$ is injective on $\mathbb{R}$ by directly showing that if $f(x_1)= f(x_2)$, then $x_1= x_2$ is just fine. However, this type of approach is not always the simplest approach. There are many approaches to showing a function is injective - each with pros/cons, depending on the function (which obviously includes the datum of their domain/codomain). For instance, it might be simpler to show the equivalent definition of that if $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

For instance, in this approach suppose that $x_1, x_2 \geq 1$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$. Without loss of generality, assume $x_1 < x_2$. But but then...
$$
\begin{split}
x_1 &< x_2 \\
x_1^3 &< x_2^3 \\
x_1 + x_1^3 &< x_2 + x_2^3 \\
f(x_1) &< f(x_2)
\end{split}
$$
The downside for this approach being that one obviously may need several cases because the above proves this only for $x_1, x_2$. [There are a few 'clever' approaches that can do this in less than 4 cases or at least (slightly) avoid cases. But even with less work from cases, I would argue this is now a mark against it for the need of being 'clever'.]

An approach that (in my experience) is typically avoid in a discrete course or a introductory proofs course (where one typically first sees this), is a Calculus approach - even when students are familiar with it. For instance, let's prove this immediately using an (even easier proved) result: recall a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing if for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$. Similarly, $f$ is decreasing if for all $x, y$ with $x < y$, then $f(x) > f(y)$.

**Proposition.** If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function, then $f$ is injective.

*Proof.* Suppose to the contrary that $f(x)= f(y)$ but $x \neq y$. Then $x < y$ or $y < x$. Without loss of generality, assume $x < y$. But because $f$ is increasing, $f(x) < f(y)$, a contradiction.

You can similarly prove that if $f$ is decreasing, then $f$ is injective. [Note: these results are false if $f$ is merely nondecreasing or nonincreasing.]

We can now show that $f(x)= x + x^3$ is injective rather quickly. We know that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)= 3x^2 + 1 \geq 0$ (because $x^2 \geq 0$). But because $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, we know that $f$ is an increasing function. But then $f$ is injective.

This type of proof approach (for the functions it applies to), is "typically" fast but does obscure what is "going on" in an injective function - again, pros and cons.